# Find the genres that have at least 2 same directors, then print common genres and director id?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sql-server-group-concat

The dataset is like this:

```
g1 = {d1,d3,d5}
g2 = {d1,d3,d2}
g3 = {d4,d3,d5}
```

I have the following table called director_genre:

```
      director_id | genre       
       d1           g1
       d1           g2
       d2           g2
       d3           g1
       d3           g2
       d3           g3
       d4           g3
       d5           g1
       d5           g3
```

The output I want is

```
      genre |  director_id       
       g1      d1,d3,d5
       g2      d1,d3
       g3      d3,d5
```

The query I thought of is

```
SELECT genre
FROM director_genre
GROUP BY genre;
```

After this, I am not to put the logic as asked in the question.
Please help me to get this done.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the first record to say `g1 | d1,d2,d5`? And look into the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function

Comment: It should be  

g1  |    d1,d3,d5


NOTE: d2 should not be in the list as it is not common for at least 2 same directors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following query:

```
SELECT d.genre, GROUP_CONCAT(director_id)
FROM director_genre d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM director_genre d2
              WHERE d.director_id = d2.director_id AND d.genre <> d2.genre
)
GROUP BY d.genre;
```

The nested subquery will select only records of directors who are associated with at least 2 genres (for each record in `d` it looks whether there exists a record in `d2` with the same `director_id` but different `genre`). Then they will be grouped by `genre`.

Comment: I have edited the question to correct my output, please have a look and then tell me does your solution works for this output also?

Comment: I think I get what you need now. For each genre, you want a list of directors who are associated with at least 2 different genres. I've updated the code.

Comment: I think, @I J solved the riddle.

Comment: @IJ thank you It's done, dear. I    think you used a correlated subquery to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You want a list of (genre, director) where the director is also associated with another genre. Then group. This could be done like so:

```
select genre, group_concat(director_id separator ', ') as directors
from dg
where exists (
  select *
  from dg as x
  where x.director_id = dg.director_id
  and x.genre <> dg.genre
)
group by genre
```